# Passing codes in URL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web

I have seen in some websites like facebook, twitter and youtuBe. Codes are being passed in the URL like the below example.

Wondering if anyone know the complete logic behind it (PHP,MYSQL). Thanks in advance.

code : QeAuADr0yL

Eg: http://instagram.com/p/QeAuADr0yL

Comment: it is a unique code, a short code, nothing special; used just to shorten the url

Comment: Those are generally encoded request parameters, which then can be used to decode and extract actual values. In some other cases, they might also be mapped to database keys, but I'd say it's less common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common codes passed in URLs are hashes. There are different algorithms, most people use md5 but there are more secure ones. You can make your hash and then if you want to, lets say, limit access to a page depending on the hash being correct, you can check the value.

url.com?x=5273909c02b8ce7ae42a4e21542b3326

```
if( $_GET['x'] == md5('hashcode') ) {
   // it matches
}else{
   // it doesn't
}
```

There are other hasing algos, [here's some docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.hash.php)

You can get these from the URL when used as part of the path via the .htaccess file.

The specific algo used for those specific sites may be custom, but there are many preset functions in PHP that will let you mimic this.

To generate a shorter one you could take the first several desired characters with the substr() function and use a database to make sure there are no collisions. When a new code is created, truncate it to the length desired and query the database to see if it has been used, insert if not.

Or you could write your own and use the same process with the database to make sure there are no collisions.

If you're going to have a lot of hashes, you might want to take some time making a good random string generator that incorporates all letters and numbers, the shorter your hash the greater the chance of collisions and the smaller the pool of possible combinations. Increasing the possible characters from 15^(characters used) with md5 to 36^(characters used) will ***greatly*** increase your pool of possible combinations.

Comment: thanks Adam, md5 generates too long code. any idea how a short code can  be generated, like code width of 10

Answer (score 1):

```
 http://instagram.com/p/QeAuADr0yL
```

The above link "QeAuADr0yL" specifies that unique identifier based on that it get the data.This identifier is encoded by using the md5() or sha1() or other..

Answer (score 1):

When the request http://instagram.com/p/QeAuADr0yL gets parsed by the apache web server, using the code stored in the .htaccess file, it knows that the first parameter value is `p` and the second parameter value is `hdashfdsahgofosa`

Your request may be translated as `www.a.com/index.php?p1=a&p2=b`

where `p1` and `p2` are variables and `a` and `b` are theyr values

these values are available using `$_GET['a']` and `$_GET['b']` method;

i will give you a full example of a htaccess file and the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/(product)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&product=$3 [NC,L]
```

the above code looks like `www.a.com/aBcdE/product-1836455` in the browser

and it is being translated as :

```
$action = aBcde;

$product = 1836455;
```

the first parameter can have values beetween a-z and/or A-Z
parameter 2 has values beetween a-z A-Z 0-9 -

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/(producator)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&producator=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(producator)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&producator=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/(producatorx)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&producatorx=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(producatorx)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&producatorx=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(tag)/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=tag&tag=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(update)-([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&saction=update&code=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/(delete)-([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&saction=delete&code=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2&saction=$3&sid=$4 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?action=details&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: if youystill need help, just ask

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the 'GET' method?

If you see a website such as www.someurl.com/?param=value&otherparam=othervalue this is known as GET.

It creates an array that can be accessed in PHP using something like

```
    <?php echo $_GET["param"]; ?>
```

This will print out the value of the param, in this case, "value".

Comment: no, he asks about www.a.com/ajkfksdhglofxds ; and why not www.a.com/this-is-what-i-want

Comment: Thanks, I know the GET method, Wondering how this code "QeAuADr0yL" coverted / how it is created when a new record is inserted in MYSQL.